# Inserting record in jOOQ without specifying column names

Tags: java, jooq

I have a table USER_ROLES that has 5 columns. Also, a class UserRole that has the same number of fields and names as USER_ROLES.

I'm trying to insert a row without specifying the column names:

```
    UserRole ur = new UserRole();
    // UserRole fields setting

    create.insertInto(USER_ROLES).values(ur).execute();
```

But I get this error when I attempt to create the row:

`The number of values must match the number of fields`

Am I forced to specify the column names?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have generated the `UserRolesRecord`, and if your `UserRole` class follows the naming conventions defined by [`DefaultRecordMapper`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DefaultRecordMapper.html), then you can load your custom `UserRole` content into the record like this:

```
UserRole ur = new UserRole();
// ...
UserRoleRecord rec = new UserRoleRecord();
rec.from(ur);
create.insertInto(USER_ROLES).set(rec).execute();
```

Comment: interesting that you cannot set the column list to a partial list and use `valuesOfRecords` because of same error, nor can you use `set` with more than one record.

Comment: @JaysonMinard: The optimal place to direct feature requests is here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following (simpler):

```
UserRole ur = new UserRole();
create.insertInto(USER_ROLES).set(ur).execute();
```